# Javascript expression calculate form 16bit to normal format

Tags: javascript

How to calculate expression in 16bit format in javascript. For example, expression [0x10] + [011] - [11] is equal to 158, how we get it?

Edit

It is not my homework, i am try to undestand how javascript converts that expression to 158. Yes, i got result as 14, but console shows me 158. So it is strange for me why console shows 158.

Comment: What have you tried so far and what are you stuck on?  We aren't here to do your homework but if there's something specific please post that here.

Comment: 0x10 + 011 - 11 returns 14 btw (0x10 is 16 in hexadecimal, 011 is 9 in octal, 11 is - 11 in decimal)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28688838/convert-a-number-into-a-16-bit-float-stored-as-bytes-and-back

Answer (score 1):

in you example,

```
[0x10] + [011] - [11]
```

equals

```
`[16]+[9]-[11]`
```

in 10 hexadecimal ,
and [`16]、[9]、[11]` are arrays. In javascript, `[a1,a2,....,an]+[b1,b2,b3...bn]`,all elements will convert to string, and the result is 
[a1.toString(),a2.toString(),....,an.toString()+b1.toString(),b2.toString(),b3.toString(),.....,bn.toString()].

In your case [0x10] + [011] ,two array have only element, so the result is '16'+'9' = '169', and then `'169'-[11]`,  '169' will be converted to number, so `169-11` the result is 158.

In javascript, two strings can use '+' to append, but '-' is not allowed, so it will try to convert string to number.

Comment: Super! Thank you very much!